# Improving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

According to Wikipedia, 'J. Shipman showed in $2007$ that if every polynomial over $F$ of prime degree has a root in $F$, then every non-constant polynomial has a root in $F$, thus $F$ is algebraically closed.' Well, I don't have the access to his paper online. Can someone explain to me the basic ideas behind his proof? Does it use logic/modeling theory?

Comment: A very quick search returned [the paper, freely available](http://www.jon-arny.com/httpdocs/Gauss/Shipman%20Intellig%20Mod%20p%20FTA.pdf).

Comment: [Here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02986170) is the paper online; moreover it is reviewed in  M. Aliabadi, M. R. Darafsheh, On maximal and minimal linear matching property, Algebra and discrete mathematics, Volume 15 (2013). Number 2. pp. 174–178

Comment: Thanks, somehow I couldn't a free version...